# can you add two elements to a function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Not sure if i am doing something wrong here, the second animation fires off but not the first??

```
<script>
  jQuery(function () {
    var element = jQuery('#innerBox' && '#innerBoxRight');
    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
      if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 600) {
        element.addClass('animateMe');
      } else {
        element.removeClass('animateMe');
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: The jQuery selector follows the standard selector rules. To select multiple elements, use a comma separator. `jQuery('#innerBox, #innerBoxRight');`.

Comment: I did try that initially, but when i use jQuery('#innerBox', '#innerBoxRight'); its only added and removing the class 'animateMe' to the second id '#innerRight'

Comment: Neither of us suggested `('#innerBox', '#innerBoxRight')` - check where your `'` are and ours are (ok, mine got split across two lines, but there's still no `', '` just `,`)

Comment: Thank you, error on my part not looking correctly, it worked. Thank you for the help